# Request progress in http headers in go

Tags: http, go, clickhouse

It is possible for the server to send HTTP headers multiple times in response before starting to send the body.
For example clickhouse does this to report progress.

From https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/interfaces/http/amp/ :

```
X-ClickHouse-Progress: {"read_rows":"2752512","read_bytes":"240570816","total_rows_to_read":"8880128"}
X-ClickHouse-Progress: {"read_rows":"5439488","read_bytes":"482285394","total_rows_to_read":"8880128"}
X-ClickHouse-Progress: {"read_rows":"8783786","read_bytes":"819092887","total_rows_to_read":"8880128"}
```

How do I read updating headers in Go? When I tried to get the values of response.Header multiple times it does stays the same.

Here is the code fragment I use to try to get updating headers.

```
    //
    // Create query
    //

    progressQ := fmt.Sprintf("SELECT * from system.numbers limit 10000000")
    ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(be.ctx, time.Second*15)
    defer cancel()

    //
    // Prepare HTTP request
    //

    req, err := http.NewRequestWithContext(ctx, http.MethodPost, be.url, strings.NewReader(progressQ))
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    //
    // Set URL query
    //

    q := req.URL.Query()

    q.Set("wait_end_of_query", "1")
    q.Set("send_progress_in_http_headers", "1")

    req.URL.RawQuery = q.Encode()

    //
    // Perform request
    //
    resp, err := be.cli.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    for {
        select {
        case <-time.After(time.Second / 10):
            fmt.Println(resp.Header.Values("X-Clickhouse-Summary"))
        case <-ctx.Done():
            goto after
        }
    }
after:
```

The result looks like

```
[{"read_rows":"10002432","read_bytes":"80019456","written_rows":"0","written_bytes":"0","total_rows_to_read":"0"}]
[{"read_rows":"10002432","read_bytes":"80019456","written_rows":"0","written_bytes":"0","total_rows_to_read":"0"}]
[{"read_rows":"10002432","read_bytes":"80019456","written_rows":"0","written_bytes":"0","total_rows_to_read":"0"}]
```

Which differs from the example I have seen in https://altinity.com/blog/2018/9/28/progress-reports-for-long-running-queries-via-http-protocol

Comment: You can use `Values()` to get all values: https://play.golang.org/p/qzBlbY4DVpk. Doubt this would be very useful though, because (in the standard library) you can only access the headers after the full response has been read.

Comment: @EmilePels where does it say that I can only access header after the response has been read? I am able to read headers without reading the response, however I don't get the updated values.

Comment: Actually everything is much simpler if you replace HTTP with GRPC. CH supports GRPC for long time. Native CH (tcp) protocol also can provide it much easier. The problem with HTTP is much deeper, you cannot get HTTP Headers if an HTTP Body has began, but CH executes queries in streaming manner.

Answer (score 0):

The standard library cannot do what you're asking.

The standard library's HTTP client waits until all headers are read, before returning the `*http.Response` object.

You'll need to implement your own HTTP client to get this behavior.

You may be able to take advantage of the [DialContext](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#Transport) field of the `http.Transport` type to wrap the standard network layer used by the standard `http.Client`.  This could allow you to inspect the response before it's parsed by the standard library, potentially reporting headers as they are read.

Answer (score 0):

I see the problem with your snippet: you're requesting `"X-Clickhouse-Summary"` when progress is reported in `"X-ClickHouse-Progress"`. If you change the header name, it should return you the slice of header values you're expecting to get.

As @Flimzy mentioned, golang HTTP standard library will return all headers at once. So there's no extra point in the loop.

Comment: `"X-Clickhouse-Summary"` is a stale header, and, frankly, I would use this one instead of poking around `"X-Clickhouse-Progress"`.

Comment: This does not answer the question. The standard library's HTTP client library will wait until all headers have been received before returning. The OP wants to check the status of each header instance as it arrives.

Comment: I **think** the question is how to read updates of the progress from the ClickHouse. The author has already done a snippet to read the headers from the response with the standard Go library.

Comment: > >The standard library's HTTP client library will wait until all headers have been received before returning.

that's actually true

Comment: If the question is simpy "How to read the most recent header sent by clickhouse", it would be: `h := resp.Header.Get("X-Clickhouse-Summary"); final := h[len(h)-1]` to get the last value.  But I'm pretty sure that's not the gist of the question.